# Are there ANY ways to USE object id in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Eclipse debugger displays object ids in expression and variable views, like this

[image]

Is it possible to utilize this data in any other way than just starring at it?

I can't print it, can't store it and etc.

Are there any ways to USE it?

May be in some scripting?

(i know i can write it down on paper or keep in mind to compare instances)